# Nginx on vagrant not loaded assets for symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, vagrant, symfony-2.1

I have problem with my website, all assets(css,js,fonts) not loaded.
My configuration :

```
server {
    listen                80;

    server_name           shop.dev;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/test.dev.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/test.dev.error.log;

    location / {
        #index app_dev.php;
        #try_files $uri /app_dev.php?$args;
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        root  /home/vagrant/Workspace/shop/web;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    sendfile off;
}
```

I use vagrant machine. Exist a solution? Help me please!!

Comment: Not loaded, you mean 404 error on your browser's debug bar? Have you dump the assets `app/console assetic:dump`?